# Choosing components to clone ZX80

Tags: components, memory, cpu, non-volatile-memory

I have an *idee fixe* to make a clone of Sinclair's [ZX80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80) computer.

So now I'm trying to find out which ICs I need for the basic prototype - and here are a few questions:

- it seems `Z84C00xxx` is a modern substitution for original Z80 processor, right?
- for SRAM, will `UT62xx` or `LY62xx` be the proper choice (I think of 6264 or 62256 chips, preferably in DIP, though it would not be hard to manage SOIC also);
- what to use for ROM? FLASH-chips I can find usually contain megabits of memory while I only need few kilobytes - would EEPROM will do instead? Though it seems there are not very much with parallel interface, but I believe I can get along with Atmel's (like `AT28C256`)? I also had idea that I can use some MCU with enough pin count and internal flash instead, but I suspect it will not give good timing (unless I pump the flash content to RAM at first).
- what series for discrete logic chips I should prefer, I believe `74HCxx` or `74HCTxxx` should be ok with the given CPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z84C00xxx is not exactly 'modern', but it *is* still available new. Another advantage is that being CMOS it uses much less power than the NMOS version. It is specified to work at TTL logic levels, so for best compatibility I would use HCT logic chips.

For SRAM I would use a 62256 (32kx8) because they are readily available and often cheaper than smaller capacity static RAMs. If you can't get it in DIP then use a SOIC to DIP adapter board.

For ROM you can use either EPROM or (parallel) EEPROM. I prefer EEPROMs because they are quicker to program and don't need a UV lamp for erasing. The AT28C64 (8kx8) is readily available in DIP package at a good price.

Comment: one of the chips is a ULA uncommitted logic array. this might be hard to find information on as it is custom programmed as well as the physical replacement.

Comment: I believe there were no ULA in ZX80, they appeared in ZX81 (if we believe wiki). Anyway the general principles of wiring ROM, RAM and CPU do not depend a lot on ULA so I hope that at I can at least create a working prototype. Though of course I'll need a ROM firmware also...